# Psalm: Unable to determine the type that $x is being assigned to

Tags: php, psalm-php

I have the following code and want to get it through Psalm static checks:

```
if (
    empty($sessions[$token]->product)
    || !is_object($sessions[$token]->product)
) {
     continue;
}

if (
    empty($sessions[$token]->product->view_list)
    || !is_array($sessions[$token]->product->view_list)
) {
    continue;
}

foreach ($sessions[$token]->product->view_list as $view) {
    if (!($view instanceof stdClass) || empty($view->color_list) || !is_array($view->color_list)) {
        continue;
    }
    ...
```

I am getting

```
ERROR: MixedAssignment
at ...
Unable to determine the type that $view is being assigned to (see https://psalm.dev/032)
                foreach ($sessions[$token]->product->view_list as $view) {
```

As you can see I tried in the foreach to already ensure the type of `$view` (it comes from an external API), but Psalm is not convinced.

I also tried a type annotation /** @var stdClass $view */ but this does not seem right and also not work.

EDIT: if I use a typehint, phpstan complains to use an assert. I also don't want to use an assert, because it would break the flow, I want to continue instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```php
if (
    empty($sessions[$token]->product->view_list)
    || !is_array($sessions[$token]->product->view_list)
) {
    continue;
}

//* @var array $list */
$list = $sessions[$token]->product->view_list;

foreach ($list as $view) {
    if (!($view instanceof stdClass) || empty($view->color_list) || !is_array($view->color_list)) {
        continue;
    }
    ...
```

Read more: https://psalm.dev/articles/easier-to-diagnose-mixed-issues

Comment: Okay, that basically works.

but if I still keep the actual check (to continue in case the input is wrong), I get

`Docblock-defined type stdClass for $view is always stdClass (see https://psalm.dev/155)                     if (!($view instanceof stdClass) || empty($view->color_list) || !is_array($view->color_list)) {`

Comment: So $list is an array of unknown type.
You should mark it as /** @var array $list */
Then you check if $view is instance of stdClass.

Comment: Mh, the problem I am seeing is, that as soon as I use a docblock, it says my check for the actual type is redudant, but of course the doc block does not check anything, so I want to prefer a real check ...

Answer (score 0):

So this seems to make psalm (and myself, coworkers, customer) happy:

```
$list = $sessions[$token]->product->view_list ?? [];

if (!is_array($list)) {
    continue;
}

/** @var mixed $view */
foreach ($list as $view) {
    if (!($view instanceof stdClass) || empty($view->color_list) || !is_array($view->color_list)) {
        continue;
    }
```

But PHPStorm complains about the @var mixed $view ... hmm .. okay